# Visual Studio - Web Test question - run 1 test multiple times

Tags: visual-studio, webtest

I have created a Web-Test in Visual Studio, using the browser recording tool in Internet Explorer.

Once I have the Web-Test, I am able to replay the test and make sure that the steps run correctly.

Now what I would like to do is run the test N number of times. (my goal is to be able to capture the 10 run times and make sure they are all within a given range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is:

Tests menu > Edit Test Settings > (choose your test settings) > Web Test > Fixed Run Count

Set the count to 10, and when you re-run your test it will run 10 times in a row.

*However*, the better way to do this is to:

- add a value to the Response Time Goal property for each request in your WebTest (click Set Request Details in the WebTest mini-toolbar)
- create a LoadTest
- add your WebTest to the LoadTest
- in Scenario settings, set a constant user load of 1
- in Run Settings set Use Iterations to true, and set Test Iterations to 10.

In a LoadTest result you get various summarized statistics and it will count how many requests exceeded the response time goal, so you don't have to do this manually.

Comment: Do you know how we can set the user count dynamically via code?